# php code to split the value from button

Tags: php

I have a button in which i am displaying **Road Vs rail**

But i need to only send **rail** value from button in condition...not complete **Road Vs rail**

So how can i split the value and send the original value rail after submit.

```
 <?php 
    foreach($modes as &$mo) {  
        $temp = "Road Vs "; 
        $mo = strtolower($mo);
     ?>
            <input name="data[Customer][mode]" class="railbtn" type="submit" id="mode" value="<?php echo $mo; ?>">
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: @Noman A `$mo` is one `$modes`

Comment: $mo contain value like rail or air likewise...

Comment: i need to send only rail in code but the values display on  button is  Raod Vs rail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a button instead of an input

```
<button name="data[Customer][mode]" class="railbtn" id="mode" value="<?= $mo; ?>">
    <?= $tmp.$mo =>
</button>
```

So the label of the button will be `Road Vs rail` but in your POST or GET data you'll see `data[Customer][mode] = rail`

Answer (score 0):

Use explode() function where Vs would be haystack and $mo is str. Then from the transferred array take last item as rail is at last.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="fake_transport" value="road vs rail"/>
    <?php
        $rail_found = TRUE;
        if (!($rail_found))
        {
            $transport = 'road';
        }
        else
        {
            $transport = 'rail';
        }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="real_transport" value="<?= $transport ?>"/>
</form>
```

you can now do yours checks with the real_transport variable, and let the fake one be displayed to the user.